# Procedural Question for Upgrading Hundreds of Critical RDS Databases

Tags: amazon-rds

I am looking for some advice on a procedural issue I have been running into since moving to RDS.

In the last couple of years we have moved around 300 of our critical databases to Aurora RDS. I have found that nearly 100% of my time has been coordinating/planning mandatory RDS upgrades for applications that cannot withstand more than a couple minutes of downtime or that require coordiantion with app teams to stop/start their applications.

When my company used self hosted databases, I was admittedly pretty bad at keeping servers patched and on recent versions. I would typically only upgrade when support was coming to an end, but this allowed me to skip some versions and carefully plan minimal downtime strategies for every critial application. But I no longer have that luxury with RDS databases and AWS's mandatory upgrade deadlines.

I am familiar with the minimal downtime strategies for RDS maintenance/upgrades, but I find myself spending all of my time notifying app teams that we need to upgrade, discussing downtime and upgrade strategy, testing upgrades, schduling and submitting change control tickets for each database, etc. I go through this process with every required upgrade and have barely been able to keep up (currently working on Aurora v3 upgrades). So my question is more around procedure..

How are DBAs at other companies with 300+ critical databses managing RDS upgrades? Are you requiring application teams to agree to set maintenance windows? Do you use the same minimal downtime strategy for all databases and script/automate it? Do you schedule the upgrade and submit change control tickets or reqire the application teams to do that?

Any advice you can provide on your RDS maintenance/upgrade procedures would be much appreciated. Lately it seems that RDS databases have become way more of a handul than our old self hosted servers, so I'm sure there has to be a better way.

Thanks!